# How to install AMD Catalyst 15.7 (fglrx 15.20.1046) on Kali 2.0 (Sana)?

Tags: linux, gnome, fglrx, amd-graphics, dkms

Today, I downloaded "Kali 2.0" and try to install "Catalyst 15.7" using the following guide:

> [How to install AMD Catalyst 15.7 (fglrx 15.20.1046) on Debian 8 (Jessie)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222000/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-15-7-fglrx-15-20-1046-on-debian-8-jessie/222016#222016)

But for some reason after starting "Kali 2.0" showed me a black screen.

Answer (score 2):

** Update 2045/09/21 **

- New links for mutter packages

---

To install Catalyst 15.7 on Kali 2.0 we have to be very careful. I try to explain briefly where the driver is installed.

First of all, we know that Kali 2.0 is based on Debian 8, therefore, when the X server starts loading the driver modules, it does so within the directory /usr/lib. This happens in Debian.

When the installation script of Catalyst starts running, it detects the architecture of our computer and look for the following folders in the following order: If architecture is x86_x64 will search for the /usr/lib64 directory, if the directory does not exist, then use the /usr/lib for installation. Something similar happens to the i386 architecture.

Kali has both directories, /usr/lib and /usr/lib64. Earlier it was mentioned that Kali is based on Debian, so in Kali, the X server will load the modules of the driver from the directory /usr/lib but because Kali also has the /usr/lib64 directory, when installing Catalyst this will be installed on /usr/lib64 directory and not on /usr/lib which is where it should be installed.

To correct the above problem, we have to rename the directories /usr/lib64 and /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu adding a point before the name, this will cause directories be hidden, and so the script installation will not find them and instead will use /usr/lib to install the driver.

Execute the following commands to perform a successful installation.

First we rename directories:

> `mv /usr/lib64 /usr/.lib64`
>
> `mv /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/.x86_64-linux-gnu`

Since Kali has the kernel 4.0 we will need to patch Catalyst to make it work with that version of the kernel, but we can save this step by downloading the following package already patched for me.

> [AMD Catalyst 15.7](https://mega.co.nz/#!249nkZ6D!G_QanBu2lj5N3MnbHtC3kQLleV5QaSSE51iwfosnyn0)

Before we begin, we need to install some dependencies, so we will open a terminal and execute the following command:

> `apt-get install gcc g++ make dkms fakeroot`

After downloading Catalyst, we must unpack. In the folder where you unpack Catalyst we will open a terminal and run the following commands:

> `cd Setup-Experimental`
>
> `mkdir /lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/build/include/linux`
>
> `cp /usr/include/linux/version.h /lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/build/include/linux/`
>
> `sh ati-installer.sh 15.20 --install`

Once the driver is installed, it will ask if you want to restart the computer. Select "no".

Now we need to create a configuration file for the X server, so execute the following command:

> `aticonfig --initial`

Note: If you need to use different options with aticonfig command, please read the help of it, running in a terminal the following command:

> `aticonfig --help`

By default, Kali comes with GNOME, so we have to take the following steps if we want GNOME to work properly.

Unfortunately Catalyst has some compatibility issues with GNOME, so, to correct, we must run in a terminal the following commands:

> `echo "export COGL_DRIVER=gl" >> /etc/environment`
>
> `echo "export COGL_OVERRIDE_GL_VERSION=1.4" >> /etc/environment`
>
> `echo "export COGL_RENDERER=GLX" >> /etc/environment`
>
> `echo "export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2" >> /etc/environment`

The previous commands helps mutter to detect the version of OpenGL, with this, the issue with GDM is solved.

Now we need help mutter to detect the version of OpenGL that our GNOME session can load properly. To do this, run in a terminal the following commands:

> `echo "export COGL_DRIVER=gl" > ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "export COGL_OVERRIDE_GL_VERSION=1.4" >> ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "export COGL_RENDERER=GLX" >> ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2" >> ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "gnome-session" >> ~/.xsession`

**GNOME laptop users only.**

In laptops, gnome-shell crash, reason for the crash is an X error asserting arguments to XRRChangeOutputProperty called from mutter-3.14.4/src/backends/x11/meta-monitor-manager-xrandr.c:output_set_presentation_xrandr

To correct this error, we must recompile "mutter" with a patch source. For users of the amd64 architecture can save the job, downloading the following files, which compiled and packed it myself.

> [gir1.2-mutter-3.0_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!vkFGzIrD!-NfAhixHLWIMUtTY_z_nzHXwbJNsBfFZJtkjBwrVaMg)
>
> [libmutter-dev_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!Sl0hzYyL!HzMCpdPC8K9_W8IUOg4Vn2YwXOaYulv-Ua3pj3LEZ4E)
>
> [libmutter0e_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!ak1g3ZoC!tR2tzS0iXLyrNFxo690J-MBqQCK5CbQH5OA8afHPz7w)
>
> [mutter_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!b1cg0RBQ!39MHA7XbAhoLgG7maEMCREGpjNN1zie8d9-C60HxNgo)
>
> [mutter-common_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_all.deb](https://mega.nz/#!WwM0BajI!525gLH37ttvo3aGtFYd6hRK_QueXlUeDng6XKpvapUA)
>
> [mutter-dbg_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!Xk0kULoY!zggnLLVzIVun1dfs-Pd4TJSJPK9H-LCgeeC4tA14bDo)

For users of the i386 architecture, soon I'll upload the packages compiled and packaged, so stay tuned to this guide.

To install the packages need to open a terminal in the folder where you downloaded the packages and run the following command:

> `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

If we have problems with some dependencies when installing packages, it is only necessary to run the following command:

> `sudo apt-get -f install`

Before restarting our computer, we must rename renamed directories initially, because they contain files that our system needs.

In a terminal run the following commands:

> `mv /usr/.lib64 /usr/lib64`
>
> `mv /usr/.x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu`

And with that we're done. Now we just have to restart our computer to enjoy Catalyst 15.7.

Comment: What about installing from Debian testing repo?

Comment: Any solution on i386?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed guide and patches. Will this still work on `Linux blackbox 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.13-1kali3 (2017-03-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`?