# How to install AMD Catalyst 15.12 (fglrx 15.302) on Kali 2.0 (Sana)?

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, amd-graphics, fglrx

Previously I faced an issue installing Catalyzt 15.7 (fglrx 15.20.1046) on Kali Sana because of the whole `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` co-existing.

Following the post [How to install AMD Catalyst 15.7 (fglrx 15.20.1046) on Kali 2.0 (Sana)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222661/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-15-7-fglrx-15-20-1046-on-kali-2-0-sana) has helped resolve the issue.

Now AMD released AMD Catalyst 15.12 (fglrx 15.302) and I was wondering if I can just run the **amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run** that comes packaged or is a specific procedure similar to move */usr/lib64* to */usr/.lib64*?

Here is some relevant info about my system

```
# fglrxinfo 
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13397 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1046

# ./fglrx-15.302/check.sh 
Detected configuration:
Architecture: x86_64 (64-bit)
X Server: XServer 1.17.2
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

**P.S.** I plan to take a backup of my system prior to the upgrade in the unfortunate event that the new `fglrx` installer messes things up and I need to roll back.

Comment: Old question, but since the AMD Catalyst major version does not change, I would expect that you'd need the same workarounds as with your currently-installed version, unless the release notes specifically say otherwise.